# Is it possible to make elastic object in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, unityscript

Is it possible to make elastic object in Unity?

I need to implement animation like of dressing gloves. When the fingers of the hand are entering in the glove, the glove fingers are expanded in diameter. When the fingers of the hand out of the glove, the glove fingers are reduced in diameter. I need to make animation like this...

I have tested Cloth, but it didn't work, as I expected.

I have project with 2 cylinders, with initial position [image: http://s6.postimg.org/kebk5w2k1/image.png] and second position [image: http://s6.postimg.org/4hcs96a5t/image.png] .

First (bigger) Cylinder1 has cloth with no gravity, smaller cylinder Cylinder2 has no Cloth...

Bottom of the Cylinder1 is not deformed, when Cylinder2 is in the Cylinder1 and in the bottom of the Cylinder1, as I expected to see.

I expected to see, what botton of the Cylinder1 will be deformed in an tension deformation.

Link to the project: https://goo.gl/OWJD26 .

Or, may be it possible to create elastic object in Blender or in DAZ3D and import it in the Unity?

I can't find any docs and examples, how to do it in simple way...

Comment: "elastic" is a very broad definition. What exact behaviour you want to implement?

Comment: I need to implement animation like of dressing gloves. When the fingers of the hand are entering in the glove, the glove fingers are expanded in diameter. When the fingers of the hand out of the glove, the glove fingers are reduced in diameter. I need to make animation like this...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly do you need, but you'll probably make some use out of Unity's [Cloth](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Cloth.html) component as well as [Joints](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/physics/joints). If you need some other kind of behaviour, you'll have to implement the changes to the mesh yourself.

Comment: I need to implement animation like of dressing gloves. When the fingers of the hand are entering in the glove, the glove fingers are expanded in diameter. When the fingers of the hand out of the glove, the glove fingers are reduced in diameter. I need to make animation like this...

Comment: Then cloth component is your choice.

Comment: I'd recommend to create the animation in Blender. Real-time cloth animation is extremely expensive. you'd need to cut down on quality a lot.

Comment: I have tested Cloth, but it didn't work, as I expected. I have project with 2 cylinders, with initial position http://s6.postimg.org/kebk5w2k1/image.png and second position http://s6.postimg.org/4hcs96a5t/image.png . First (bigger) Cylinder1 has cloth with no gravity, smaller cylinder Cylinder2 has no Cloth... Bottom of the Cylinder1 is not deformed, when Cylinder2 is in the Cylinder1 and in the bottom of the Cylinder1, as I expected to see. I expected to see, what botton of the Cylinder1 will be deformed in an tension deformation. Link to the project: https://goo.gl/OWJD26 .